# Jquery .error method replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('img').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'missing.png');
});

// Or, hide them
$("img").error(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```

This code does'nt work because .error has been removed in jquery 3.x.
What Jquery method or Javascript method can  I use to test for broken image?

Comment: Couldn't you simply have looked this up yourself? The docs give you the answer http://api.jquery.com/error/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `on`:

```
$('img').on("error", function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'missing.png');
});
```

See the [jQuery 3 migration guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed).

Comment: Thank you! Can i use only a javascript native method without jquery?

Comment: Sure. Use `document.getElementsByTagName` and call `addEventListener` on each of the matching elements.